# Does Ionic 3 have support for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, ionic3

I need to know if Ionic 3 has support for Arduino, because I hope to develop an Ionic app for an Arduino project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic (https://ionicframework.com/what-is-ionic) is a framework that allows you to run webapps like a "native app" for Windows, Android and iOS mobile devices. That being said and if you want, you can use hardware from the device for your app (Camera, GPS, etc).

What I think you're trying to do si to have an approach of a "nice user interface" to send commands to an arduino or to be able to do something, not a direct communication from arduino to an Ionic app.

You could run a web from the arduino to receive commands, makes the arduino to process it, run some code to check temperature, distance, whatever your sensors are, and answer that request in an http protocol.

Another way would be to send information through bluetooth and translate that into the ionic framework app. Then display anything you may create for that using the information shared among them.

In a strict way of linking Arduino and Ionic by themselves, can not be done.

Comment: thank you for above description